# dbt Power User on vscode "AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'ndarray' "

Tags: vscode-extensions, dbt

I recently installed the dbt Power User extension for vscode and I am having some problems with it.

I followed the steps for setting it up, and some aspects seem to work fine like the lineage but I am not able to right click on a model and compile it, as the error above shows up.

I believe the problem might be that it is not using the right python interpreter, but I am not sure.

I use conda in general, and I have set it up so that the interpreter at the bottom right indicates as such. If I open a terminal, I am able to run commands for dbt with no problem, that is what I have been doing so far. I am able to compile, run or do anything I need from the command line, so that part seems to be set up correctly. That makes me think, that the extension for some reason is not using the same setup.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
> Executing task: dbt compile --model MODELNAME
07:10:54  Encountered an error:
module 'numpy' has no attribute 'ndarray'
07:10:54  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\main.py", line 135, in main
    results, succeeded = handle_and_check(args)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\main.py", line 198, in handle_and_check
    task, res = run_from_args(parsed)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\main.py", line 225, in run_from_args
    task = parsed.cls.from_args(args=parsed)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\task\base.py", line 163, in from_args
    return super().from_args(args)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\task\base.py", line 98, in from_args
    config = cls.ConfigType.from_args(args)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\config\runtime.py", line 263, in from_args
    project, profile = cls.collect_parts(args)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\config\runtime.py", line 207, in collect_parts
    profile = cls.collect_profile(args=args)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\config\runtime.py", line 229, in collect_profile
    profile = cls._get_rendered_profile(args, profile_renderer, profile_name)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\config\runtime.py", line 200, in _get_rendered_profile
    return Profile.render_from_args(args, profile_renderer, profile_name)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\config\profile.py", line 428, in render_from_args
    return cls.from_raw_profiles(
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\config\profile.py", line 394, in from_raw_profiles
    return cls.from_raw_profile_info(
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\config\profile.py", line 348, in from_raw_profile_info
    credentials: Credentials = cls._credentials_from_profile(
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\config\profile.py", line 181, in _credentials_from_profile
    cls = load_plugin(typename)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\adapters\factory.py", line 202, in load_plugin
    return FACTORY.load_plugin(name)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\adapters\factory.py", line 57, in load_plugin
    mod: Any = import_module("." + name, "dbt.adapters")
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\ada`pters\snowflake\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dbt.adapters.snowflake.connections import SnowflakeConnectionManager  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbt\adapters\snowflake\connections.py", line 17, in <module>
    import snowflake.connector
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .connection import SnowflakeConnection
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 27, in <module>
    from . import errors, proxy
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .compat import BASE_EXCEPTION_CLASS
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\compat.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import constants
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\constants.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .options import pyarrow as pa
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\options.py", line 135, in <module>
    pandas, pyarrow, installed_pandas = _import_or_missing_pandas_option()
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\options.py", line 81, in _import_or_missing_pandas_option
    pandas = importlib.import_module("pandas")
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pandas._typing import F
  File "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_typing.py", line 78, in <module>
    ArrayLike = Union["ExtensionArray", np.ndarray]
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'ndarray'
```

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing the extension. I've tried to follow the set up steps again, but there has been no change.